# How could these lines of code cause the exact same program to crash sometimes but work fine others?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have a struct with an int and an array of pointers to structs:

```
//Define a struct
struct city
{
    //Declaration of struct members
    int city_num;
    struct city **connected;
};
```

and an array of 'n' of these structs:

```
struct city* cities;
cities = malloc(n*sizeof(struct city));
```

and I want to assign a pointer to one struct to the 'connected' member of another struct after allocating space for it.

```
cities[j].connected = realloc(cities[j].connected, (1*sizeof(struct city*));
cities[i].connected = realloc(cities[i].connected, (1*sizeof(struct city*));

cities[j].connected[0]=&list[i];
cities[i].connected[0]=&list[j];
```

but the program SOMETIMES crashes at the two last lines. Yesterday it was crashing like it is now, then late at night it just started working like that without me changing anything (I was just commenting the rest of the code) and today after working all morning it just decided to start crashing again a while ago. (I am using Code::Blocks 13.12)

I have put together a very simplified version of the program to show you guys what the problem is.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//Define a struct
struct city
{
    //Declaration of struct members
    int city_num;
    struct city **connected;
};

int main()
{
    int n = 2;
    struct city* cities;

    cities = malloc(n*sizeof(struct city));

    cities[0].city_num = 1;
    cities[1].city_num = 2;

    cities[0].connected = realloc(cities[0].connected, (1*sizeof(struct city*)));
    cities[1].connected = realloc(cities[1].connected, (1*sizeof(struct city*)));

    //CRASHES AT THESE TWO LINES <-------------------------------------------------
    cities[0].connected[0]=&cities[1];
    cities[1].connected[0]=&cities[0];

    //I have ommitted the memory freeing from this code as the problem is caused above this point

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the field 'connected' in the struct is expecting to point to an array of pointers to instances of the struct.  Where each instances contains a 'connected' field that is expecting a pointer to an array of pointers to instances of the struct .......  strongly suggest the struct be redesigned to not be recursive,

Comment: in this kind of line: ' cities[1].connected = realloc(cities[1].connected, (1*sizeof(struct city*)));'  1) the '1*' is not needed and just clutters the code.  2) the returned value from realloc() needs to be checked to assure the operation was successful, BEFORE setting the targert variable 'cities[1].connected  otherwise the original malloc'd memory pointer will be lost, resulting in a memory leak.

Comment: the returned value from malloc needs to be checked (!=NULL) before using it  Otherwise the following code will be trying to access an offset from address 0, resulting in undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event

Comment: there iare multiple memory leaks in the code, for instance the lines marked as the crash location both overlay the returned value from realloc() with some other pointer.  in the two lines before that, there is ONLY ONE address pointer, contained inthe variable 'cities', however, the code is trying realloc some field within the cities struct, which doesn't contain any valid pointer, not even NULL

Comment: i have added malloc for the first allocation and realloc in following cases when I want to add more to the array.. this is a very simplified version just used to uncover the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realloc()` reallocates memory when more is required than was previously allocated by `malloc()` or `calloc()`.

But it also works when the first parameter passed is `NULL`.

So to answer your question the **reason your code sometimes works and sometimes does not**, is because although the pointer passed has not been initialised by a previous allocation, it *happens* to be sometimes `NULL`.

Comment: okay thanks! it was really weird because it worked continuously, not like one run was fine and the next one failed.

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to `realloc()` must be an address that was returned by `malloc()`, or a previous call to `realloc()`.

The following line:

```
cities[0].connected = realloc(cities[0].connected, (1*sizeof(struct city*)));
```

Passes `cities[0].connected`, which does not contain the address returned by one of these functions. In fact, it hasn't been initialized at all! Therefore, this is an invalid call to `realloc()`.

This is considered *undefined behavior*, and is subject to crash your code. However, since we have no idea what address you are passing and it is likely a different address each time, then it might sometimes no crash. But it is always wrong.

*Note: If you pass `NULL` as the first argument, then `realloc()` will work like `malloc()`. But here you are passing an unitialized value, which could be anything.*

You need to do something like this:

```
cities[0].connected = malloc(1*sizeof(struct city*));
```

Note that the code to free up this memory just became a bit more complex, as you'll need to free each of these addresses.

Comment: i read somewhere online that realloc could be used on its own without malloc

Comment: That's true. You can pass `NULL` and then it works like `malloc()`. But your argument is not initialized. It could be any value here.